# Value of derivative of Dirichlet L-function at $s=0$ for $\chi \neq \chi_{0}$

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How to calculate the expression for $L^{'} (0, \chi) $ when $\chi$ is non principal even character mod $q$ i.e, $\chi(-1)=1$ ?

---

Here we know that

$L(s,\chi)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\chi(n)}{n^{s}}$ and $L^{'}(s,\chi)= -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\chi(n) \log n}{n^{s}}$.
Then $L^{'}(0,\chi)= -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\chi(n) \log n$.

Can we solve this by Euler-Maclaurin summation formula with the partial sum $\sum_{n\leq x}\chi(n) \log n$?

Comment: Those Dirichlet series only converge when Re$(s)>0$, and therefore they can't be used to calculate $L(0,\chi)$ or $L'(0,\chi)$. (Note that the summand doesn't even tend to $0$, so the series can't possibly converge.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way would be to combine the functional equation for Dirichlet $L$-functions,
$$
L(s,\chi) = \varepsilon(\chi) 2^s \pi^{s-1} q^{1/2-s} \sin \left( \frac{\pi}{2} (s + a) \right)  \Gamma(1-s) L(1-s, \overline{\chi}),
$$
with the evaluation of $L'(1,\overline\chi)$ using the Dirichlet series in the OP. In this case, the assumption that $\chi$ is even (which makes $a=0$ in the notation of the above formula) simplies the calculation dramatically, and the answer is
$$
L'(0,\chi) = \frac{\varepsilon(\chi)\sqrt{q}}2L'(1,\overline\chi).
$$
Here, $\varepsilon(\chi) = \frac{\tau(\chi)}{\sqrt{q}}$
where $\tau(\chi) = \sum_{n=1}^q \chi(n)e^{2\pi in/q}$ is the Gauss sum; so the formula can be simplified to
$$
L'(0,\chi) = \frac{\tau(\chi)}2L'(1,\overline\chi).
$$