# Expression for derivative of Dirichlet L- function

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

How can we find an expression for the derivative of Dirichlet L- function $L(s,\chi )$ with respect to s?

---

Is it possible to calculate the derivative with the help of its functional equation at positive integer?

As we have , for $\chi(-1)=1$,
$L^{'}(0,\chi) = \frac{\tau(\chi)}{2} L^{'}(1,\overline{\chi}) $

where $\tau(\chi) $ is Gauss sum.

Comment: See the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4144929/value-of-derivative-of-dirichlet-l-function-at-s-0-for-chi-neq-chi-0) for the last statement.

Comment: What sort of expression are you looking for? If you can compute $L(s, \chi)$, then you can use Cauchy's theorem to represent $L^{(n)}(s, \chi)$ as a contour integral of $L(s, \chi)$. In complete generality you could use an *approximate functional equation* and differentiate it. The various expressions will depend on your preferred description of continuation.